# Bash pipe delimited string into command's arguments

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

Let's Encrypt allows you to specify multiple allowed domains:

```
certbot certonly -d foo.example.com -d bar.example.com
```

Is there a way to pipe a comma-delimited string so that each delimited element is used as an argument? Something like:

```
echo 'foo.example.com,bar.example.com' | magic_function 'certbot certonly {-d}'
```

This feels similar to `xargs`, but I want all the tokens to end up given to the same process.

(It turns out that certbot will just accept a comma-delimited list of domains, but what if it didn't?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this calls for use of an array to actually construct your command. Assuming you have a comma de-limited list of URLs as the input. First read them on to an array

```
inputStr='foo.example.com,bar.example.com'
IFS=, read -ra urlList <<<"$inputStr"
```

Now construct the command with the `-d` switch using an array.

```
domainList=()
for url in "${urlList[@]}"; do
    domainList+=(-d "$url")
done
```

Now pass the constructed array to the command

```
certbot certonly "${domainList[@]}"
```

Expanding on this, simply this to make it a function that takes a list of URLs and runs the command on it

```
runCertbot() {
    (( $# )) || { printf 'insufficient args provided\n' >&2; return 1; }
    IFS=, read -ra urlList <<<"$@"
    domainList=()
    for url in "${urlList[@]}"; do
        domainList+=(-d "$url")
    done
    certbot certonly "${domainList[@]}"         
}
```

and call the function as below

```
runCertbot 'foo.example.com,bar.example.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
certbot certonly -d $(echo 'foo.example.com,bar.example.com' | sed -e 's/,/ -d /')
```

'sed' replaces every comma with ' -d '. You only need to add leading '-d'.

Comment: That works in this particular case, but it probably fails in general if any of the comma-delimited items contain spaces, `*`, `?`, or other interesting characters.

Comment: All interesting characters will remain as they are. They won't be replaced, which is the point, isn't it?

Comment: @DejanD What @melpomene is saying is that your code relies on word-splitting so funny/interesting strings like `*,foo.example.com` will break your code and therefore this is not a recommended approach even though it works for this particular case. Refer to the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51671198/6176817) that handles those "interesting" cases correctly.

Comment: i actually like this solution as it is succinct and simple.  for cases where you have a level of control over the arguments being passed and not solving for the world or unknowns, it's a good solution.